# JS SDK and Login Approvals (Two-Factor Authentication)

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-oauth

I'm seeing an issue pop up with a couple users trying to authenticate to our site.  We use the JavaScript SDK just for the OAuth workflow; and the users are entering their Facebook credentials, but the redirect back just hangs. The users have Login Approvals turned on.

This could very well be a coincidence, but are there any issues with users who have Login Approvals and the JavaScript OAuth workflow?

Comment: How do I enable two-factor authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Any account that has or ever had "Login Approvals" set, returns an invalid query string. Instead of http: // redirecturl&access_token= you now get http: // redirecturl&#access_token= which is invalid.

My work around was to add clean up javascript to the http: // redirecturl page.

```
if (location.href.indexOf("&#") > 0) document.location = location.href.replace("&#", "&")
```

Have reported this to facebook at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/435673509858372